# Lucene 3.0 - why I cannot get correct hitcount?

Tags: netbeans, lucene

I am new to Lucene and I am lost when I am try to get a hitcount after search. Please help.
BTW, I am using Netbeans IDE. Thanks in advance for help.

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package pdflucene;

/**
*
* @author nigel
*/


import java.io.IOException;


import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;

import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;


public class ExtractPageContent {


public static final String inn = "/Users/nigel/Desktop/Statement_Week9/AlanWilder.pdf";
public static final String PATH = "/Users/nigel/Desktop/Statement_Week9";



public void parsePdf(String pdf) throws IOException {
     String ts="";
     String content="";
     String [] queryStrings;

 try{   
    String temp = ""; 
     PDDocument pdfdocument = PDDocument.load(pdf);   
    Integer n=pdfdocument.getNumberOfPages();
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();  

    RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory();
    stripper.setStartPage(1);
    stripper.setEndPage(4);
    stripper.setSortByPosition(false);

    pdfdocument.close();

    IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_30, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(idx, conf);
    Document mydoc = new Document();
    mydoc.add(new Field("content", "Alan is Alan not quite alan",Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.ANALYZED)); 

    writer.addDocument(mydoc) ;
    writer.close();


    IndexSearcher ss=new IndexSearcher(idx,true);
    Term t = new Term("content", "Alan");
    TermQuery pq= new TermQuery(t);


    int results = ss.search(pq,1).totalHits;
    System.out.println("total hits: " + results);


    ss.close();

   System.out.println("number of pages " + n);
   }catch(Exception e){ 
      System.out.println("Something Wrong at "+e.getMessage());
    }   



}



 /**
 * Main method.
 * @param    args    no arguments needed
 * @throws IOException
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new ExtractPageContent().parsePdf(inn);
  }
}
```

Comment: what kind of problem in particular do you experience? Does it raise an exception?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why are you getting zero hits is because the way you index information and the way you query is different.

When you index your information, you use `StandardAnalyzer` which internally uses `LowerCaseFilter`, and all your data sits lowercased inside the index.

When you query, you construct "raw" query (using `TermQuery`) which isn't lowercasing your term value. If you would change line

```
Term t = new Term("content", "Alan");
```

into

```
Term t = new Term("content", "alan");
```

you would get desired result. Obviously, this is a bad approach - you want to achieve the same by parsing query and reusing the same analyzer, e.g.:

```
Query q = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(
                    Version.LUCENE_30,
                    "content:Alan",
                    new String[]{"content"},
                    new BooleanClause.Occur[] {BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD},
                    analyzer
);
```

You can probably use different type of query, but you got the idea.

p.s. next time do not include information which is irrelevant to the problem (PDF stuff).